# change NetworkImageView to ImageView?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview

I have a NetworkImageView but I want to use, instead, a ImageView to cache images instead of get it from network all the time.

Any ideas how to change it?

```
  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        //Views
        public NetworkImageView imageView;
        public TextView textViewName;
        public TextView textViewPublisher;

        //Initializing Views
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);
            textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            textViewPublisher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPublisher);
            textViewName.setClickable(true);
            textViewName.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
```

Comment: You can Use Glide  , UniversalImageLoder Library for Image Loading .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in layout From `<NetworkImageView` with `<ImageView` and then change your viewholder from  `public NetworkImageView imageView;` with `public ImageView imageView;` and from `imageView = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);` with `imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewHero);`

hope this helps you

you can't set image in ImageView directly. you have to convert that image in Bitmap and then set

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        Log.e("src",src);
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        Log.e("Bitmap","returned");
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then set to imageview :

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(url));
```

Comment: it gives me an error: cannot find symbol method setImageUrl(String,ImageLoader)

Answer (score 3):

You can used fresco lib for loading images.
It have lots of features.
https://github.com/facebook/fresco

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Easy to use and it provides caching mechanism.